# Maintain image aspect ratio in nested flexbox container on IE11

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm using flexbox to display a row of blocks. Each block is using flexbox to display a column of elements. One of the elements is an image that needs to maintain its aspect ratio. The code below is a simplified version of my code that illustrates what I'm trying to do.

In Chrome the images scale to 186px x 186px. In IE11 they display 186px x 500px. I've tried wrapping the images in another div and setting its height and/or width to 100%, but nothing works for both Chrome and IE11.

```css
section {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.block {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 1 0 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.block img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="block">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="">
            <h2>Block title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="">
            <h2>Block title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="">
            <h2>Block title</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Really interesting how it work correctly (230 x 230) using Edge

Comment: No kidding. How long until we can ditch IE entirely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like adding `min-height: 1px;` to the `img` is the solution. I wish I had a good explanation for why this works. [Here's the best I could find](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/75#issuecomment-161800607):

> ... My best guess is that the min-height forces IE to recalculate the
>   height of the rendered content after all of the resizing, and that
>   makes it realize that the height is different....

Answer (score 4):

Fellow stranger looking for fix, but featured on top answer didn't help.
Setting `min-width: 1px;` to the `img` may help you as well.